# Find same values in excel filtered range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with VBA as I'm trying to make a code that will first filter based on data on another tab and then in this filtered range it will look on one column all the values that appear twice (I need to have all these amounts marked with a color and not just the duplicate one).

So basically let's say that in Sheet2 I have in A column list of codes that I need to filter one by one on Sheet1 - A column. 
Then based on this filtering I need to check in B column the values that appear twice and color those values with let's say green color (only on the visible cells).

```
Sub filter()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim xrow As Long, firstrow As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim SearchValue As Variant

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)

    xrow = 2

    Do
        SearchValue = ws2.Cells(xrow, 1)

            ws.Range("$A$1:$B$14").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SearchValue
                   With ws.AutoFilter.Range
                        firstrow = ws.Range("A" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Row
                        lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                        'This is where the problem is
                        'how to match and make a color for each amount that appears twice in column B in this filtered range

                   End With

    xrow = xrow + 1
    Loop Until ws2.Cells(xrow, 1) = ""
End Sub
```

Edit: I ended up doing without filtering, this works for me in case anyone wonders:

```
xrow = 2
Do
    SearchValue = ws2.Cells(xrow, 1)
    lastrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        For x = 2 To lastrow
            For y = x + 1 To lastrow
                    If ws.Cells(x, 1) = SearchValue And ws.Cells(y, 1) = SearchValue And ws.Cells(x, 2) = ws.Cells(y, 2) Then
                        ws.Cells(x, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                        ws.Cells(y, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                   Else
                    End If
            Next y
         Next x

    xrow = xrow + 1
Loop Until ws2.Cells(xrow, 1) = ""
```

As a result the macro would check all codes for same values and I would have those marked with green color.
So if in Sheet1 in A column I have 2 exact same codes for example 1111 and those have the same value - 30 then this 30 would be marked with green in both lines but if the code 1111 has also value 25, this wouldn't be marked with a color.

Comment: Have you tried any conditional formatting?  one for `if(countifs(rng1,val1,rng2, val2))>1` another for `= 1` for one color each scenario?

Comment: You could add some screenshot to better explain why your current macro isn't working. At a fisrt glance/blind shot, it seems a work for a `Dictionary` object

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I ended up doing this in different way in the end without filtering. I added the new code to the original post in case anyone is interested